# Paypal Developer Beta: Test transaction not listed in Sandbox Business account

Tags: c#, .net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

So..... it seems Paypal Developer decided to change everything on their brand new website as of 2013, and it's making my life miserable for the past few days. Please note that I'm totally new to integrating Paypal in website. I tried to follow this tutorial, but it's from 2009: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42894/Introduction-to-PayPal-for-C-ASP-NET-developers

I am not using the Paypal Api. Don't know if i should?

Here's what I did:

1) I went to https://developer.paypal.com/ and logged in with my own paypal account.

2) This is one of the tricky part. In the tutorials i've checked, there was an option to create "preconfigured test accounts", but it's not available anymore. So i created two test accounts (or so i think) with their new Create Account button. One personal (buyer) and one Business (seller). No tutorials mentionned if the mail adress of those test accounts needs to exists or if they can be fictitious... i made the buyer a real one (which i created for this test) and the seller a fictitious one.

3) In my Test Seller Account, I activated AutoReturn with my CallbackUrl and I activated Payment Data Transfer (PDT) and placed the token in my web.config.

4) Following the tutorial yet again, i created my .Net Visual Studio project. Something really simple, a Default.aspx, a Callback.aspx and a Cancelled.aspx. Callback for checking if the transaction was a success and Cancelled to check if the user cancelled the transaction.

5) Here is the code/Paypal hiddenfield variables of Default.aspx. Nothing really fancy:

```
<form id="form1" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" runat="server">
<div>
    <!-- Type: Buy Now/Simple Payment -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
    <!-- PayPal ID or an email address associated with your PayPal account -->
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="THE-SELLER-MAIL-ADRESS" />
    <!-- Name of service selected -->
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Forfait Regulier" />
    <!-- Currency -->
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD" />
    <!-- Return method: 2 – the buyer’s browser is redirected to the return URL by using the POST method, and all payment variables are included -->
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
    <!-- Button text -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Retourner sur Bloc D'Affaires" />
    <!-- Cancel callback url -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://dev.triarts.ca/Pages/Cancelled.aspx" />
    <!-- Amount -->
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00" />
    <!-- Don't show Shipping adress form -->
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
    <!-- Don't show seller note box -->
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" /> 
    <!-- Button -->
    <input type="submit" value="Payer" />
</div>
</form>
```

6) Code-behind of Callback.aspx, taken and adapted from the 2009 tutorial mentionned above:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string authToken = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PDTToken"];

    //read in tx token from querystring
    string txToken = Request.QueryString.Get("tx");


    string query = string.Format("cmd=_notify-synch&tx={0}&at={1}",
                          txToken, authToken);

    // Create the request back
    string url = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PayPalSubmitUrl"];
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    // Set values for the request back
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.ContentLength = query.Length;

    // Write the request back IPN strings
    StreamWriter stOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(),
                             System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
    stOut.Write(query);
    stOut.Close();

    // Do the request to PayPal and get the response
    StreamReader stIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
    string strResponse = stIn.ReadToEnd();
    stIn.Close();

    // If response was SUCCESS, parse response string and output details
    if (strResponse.StartsWith("SUCCESS"))
    {
        Label1.Text = "Success";
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "Oooops, something went wrong...";
    }
}
```

7) Up to there, it's not that complicated. Afterwards, I first login in my Paypal Developer Account. I start the project and test it out. Push the buy now button, get redirected to Paypal Sandbox Test Store as expected. I login with my buyer test account, click Pay Now. Process. Transaction Successful. The page redirects me to Callback.aspx as expected, and the Success message is shown. Not so shabby.

8) But here is the other tricky part. In the Paypal Developer site, i see the buyer/seller notifications saying that a payment was sent/received. I login as the test buyer in sandbox and check the recent activity: an entry shows that a payment was done and Completed (status). I login as the test seller, **i check the recent activity and i see no transaction entry, but the Paypal Balance grows, meaning the payment was added?!?**...

I don't understand... is this suppose to happen? Did i do something wrong? If i go live with these settings is everything gonna go wrong?

In a video tutorial, which didn't really helped me, it clearly showed a transaction entry in the seller test account. Why didn't mine showed up, or any of the bazillion test transactions i've done until now?

Can anyone make sure the process is legit? It would reassure me a great deal. I feel uncomfortable messing with money when i'm not really sure about this. Will this code be enough to create post-payment logic like update my database to mention the payment was done or cancelled? If there is an easier way, don't hesitate to tell me.

Thank you so much in advance and sorry for the epic novel.

Comment: It may be part of a Sandbox issue. The last week or so there has been problems with the Sandbox history redirecting to the Live site. Can you provide the transaction ID for one of your test payments? I'd like to look it up and research this further.

Comment: Here are 3 of a few test transactions i tried:
Transaction ID: 4TU573346J375571Y  /

Transaction ID: 1F165987SS041432U  /

Transaction ID: 54P93871C25568352

Comment: The account you're signing into is "myMechantCalice", right? I'm not able to recreate the issue. When I complete a Payment Standard button the details appear correctly in both the Seller and Buyer accounts. Can you provide a screen shot? I can use it to show the Sandbox engineers.

Comment: Yes, this is the Merchant Account. Tell me if i'm wrong, **in the Seller account, all transactions/payments received DO NOT show up on the Default/Overview page, the one we land on  after login in, is this right?** They show up in a page after clicking the "View transactions > Payments received" link. I do believe that's what confused me. I thought that the transaction showed up on the overview, as it does with the Buyer account... I just rechecked my test account and i saw all test transactions i did last week. **So, does this mean that my code is legit and would work in a Live setting?**

Comment: Here are screenshots of the last test transaction, I did today:
[Test Buyer Payment Sent history](http://postimg.org/image/dkdqms9kz/) / 
[Test Seller Payment Received History](http://postimg.org/image/m3qx4r8mv/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New Sandbox Business accounts currently have Payments Pro enabled on them by default and the account layout is different than a Standard Business or Personal account. With a Pro account you do not see the transactions on the Account Overview page when you first log in.

To view the transactions on the Pro account you need to open the History tab. You figured that out and you're good to go. I was concerned that transactions weren't appearing on the History tab but that doesn't seem to be the problem so that's a relief.

Comment: Thank you for your help Patrick. If this means my code is ok, then it was just me who freaked out. Sorry for the scare.